# How do I set up non local network folder sharing?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, remote-desktop, file-sharing, cloud

I am not a tech savvy person so this may be very easy to solve or not solvable at all, or perhaps there is a better way that I am not thinking of...

**The Situation:** 
Three (3) Desktop Computers running Windows 8 are all connected on a local wireless network. All three desktops have different users that are all apart of one small business. One (1) desktop (we'll call it Desktop A) is what I think they call the "server". It holds the main folders and files that we get access to through the other two desktop computers (we'll call them Desktops B and C).

There are two laptops for two of the desktop users (we'll call them laptop A and B). Laptops A and B are also able to connect to the wireless local network and have access to the server files when they are within the reach of the local wireless network.

**The Goal:** 
I would like to be able to access the files on Desktop A from Laptops A and B from outside of the wireless local network, for example, in a different city. Is this possible? In other words, I would like to be on a non-local wireless network with the desktop computers. Is a non-local connection possible?

**What I have considered:** 
We have Carbonite on all computers so we are able to access the files on the cloud, but I want to be able to edit, add, and delete files directly from the Desktop A while I am outside of the local network on Laptop B. I have also considered Microsoft OneDrive, but they do not allow more than one user to sign into the OneDrive Desktop Application.

**In an ideal world:**
I would like to be able to add, edit and delete files that are stored off-line on Laptop B then when Laptop B goes online, it would update to Desktop A's files and vice versa.

Everytime I think of how to do this I end up on the floor going into a mild seizure. If anyone has any advice I would love to hear it and would appreciate it very much.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understood your requirements perfectly, so this may be off the mark -- but I've been very happy with dropbox shared folders.

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because it's a completely different take on it, but some wireless routers will allow connecting a disk drive to the router, which then can be accessed both locally and from the internet.  It's not what I'd consider the "right" way to do things, but it's pretty easy to set up.  Of course, since it's a business environment, you have to know that this type of file access has much greater risks to your business data than the more secure (and very comprehensive!) method that's posted in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

An application like [NeoRouter](http://www.neorouter.com/) or [Hamachi](https://hamachi.en.softonic.com/) will be what you want. These applications will set up a VPN between computers so they will act as if there still on the same network. in all essence, you will only need to install the application that you chose onto your server and the laptops that will be in the field.

Hamachi is good at this sort of thing because you don't have anything to maintain. its more or less install, configure once, and go. However, there are still downsides to using this application. As of the last time that I used this application(2014), you were limited to only 5 devices per network for free. However, you could have as many networks that you wanted.

Neorouter is the more config able of the two. for this application, you will need to install a server part once and a client on all computers that you want to talk to each other. The pros here are you are in control of your data at all times. However, there is more that you would need to fix if something breaks...